# Excel VBA Clearcontents method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, range

The code below is from one of the first macros I wrote so I'm sure there are much better ways to do this.  This code has worked for years and recently started failing and displaying the "Clearcontents method of Range Class failed" message.

I have 2 fields where the user can enter an "X".  The intent of this code was to clear the other cells when a user enters an "X".  Pretty simple and straightforward.  Any suggestions?

This is happening on a machine with Windows 7 and a 32 bit operating system.

Thanks for the help........

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 2 And Len(Trim(Cells(19, 2))) > 0 Then
        Cells(19, 2) = UCase(Cells(19, 2))
        Cells(20, 2).ClearContents
    Else
        If Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 2 And Len(Trim(Cells(20, 2))) > 0 Then
            Cells(20, 2) = UCase(Cells(20, 2))
            Cells(19, 2).ClearContents
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: And lucky too. You can get into an infinite loop with that event handler...

Comment: Are you just trying to see if Cells(19,2) is not blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Row = 19 And Target.Column = 2 And Len(Trim(Cells(19, 2))) > 0 Then
            Cells(19, 2) = UCase(Cells(19, 2))
            Cells(20, 2).ClearContents
        Else
            If Target.Row = 20 And Target.Column = 2 And Len(Trim(Cells(20, 2))) > 0 Then
                Cells(20, 2) = UCase(Cells(20, 2))
                Cells(19, 2).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I would drop the nested `If` statement and switch to `ElseIf`

Comment: @Gary's Student...............Thanks for the suggestion.  That seemed to do the trick.  This was strange.  This code was in this particular macro for at least 10 years and never had an issue with it.  Now all of a sudden, selected users were getting the error.  Thanks again for your help,,,,,,,,Mike

Answer (score 1):

Try to change **Cells(20, 2).ClearContents** to **Cells(20, 2).value = ""**.

Or try to qualify the object Cells with the worksheet name like this: **Worksheets("putNameHere").Cells(20, 2).ClearContents**.

The code has some problems, but maybe it works...